# filter cron emails through procmail?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, procmail

I'm using postfix/mutt/procmail on a Linux/Debian and I've some trouble filtering cron emails with procmail, I just want to move them to the cron/ maildir directory, but no lucky till now. I've several other rules on .procmailrc to move emails with ^From: to a specific directory, only the cron rule doesn't work.

/etc/aliases:

```
postmaster:    root
root:          alex
```

.procmailrc:

```
:0:
* ^From: Cron Daemon <root@hellspawn>
* ^Subject: Cron .*
cron/
```

headers of a mail sent by cron:

```
Return-Path: <alex@hellspawn>
X-Original-To: alex
Delivered-To: alex@hellspawn
Received: by hellspawn (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 27E2E1920C5B; Fri, 31 Jan 2014 16:30:09 +0100 (CET)
From: Cron Daemon <root@hellspawn>
To: alex@hellspawn
Subject: Cron <alex@hellspawn> $HOME/.getmail/getmail2.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/alex>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=alex>
Message-Id: <20140131153009.27E2E1920C5B@hellspawn>
Date: Fri, 31 Jan 2014 16:30:09 +0100 (CET)
```

~/.forward (guess it is useless in this case, just given a try):

```
|/usr/bin/procmail
```

What's wrong?

**update 12/5/14**

I ended up using the negated `!` rule below with *noop* nested block `{ }` and *else* `E`, seems like is the "Cron Daemon" part of the address creating the problem.

```
:0
* ! ^From.*root@hellspawn
* ! ^Subject:.*Cron Daemon
{ }
:0 E
cron/
```

Comment: Your rules works as intended. The error must somewhere else.

Comment: Add `VERBOSE=yes` and examine the output in `procmail.log` for error indications.  See also http://partmaps.org/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: Incidentally, the lock file (when saving to a folder) and the trailing `.*` on the Subject: regex are superfluous if not outright wrong.  See also http://partmaps.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html

Comment: `VERBOSE=on` revealed that `procmail: No match on "^From:.*Cron.*root@hellspawn"`, used some variant already without success

Comment: Seems like any match on `From` isn't working (I guess is something about local users email). The first try on `Subject` only worked.